# Bootstrap thumbnails too small on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set of Bootstrap thumbnails on my web page and I have set all the images with class `.img-responsive`. When I open the page on a mobile browser the thumbnails are appearing too small and I can't even resize them with css.

Here are my thumbnails:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="images/thumbnails/traditional.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="...">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="images/thumbnails/mehndi.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="...">
        </a>
      </div>
... altogether 12 thumbnails 
    </div>
```

I have tried to edit the size of the thumbnails for mobile phone size devices with the following media query:

```
@media(max-width:767px){
    .thumbnail > img { 
    height:70px;
    width:120px;

    }
}
```

However the width doesn't seem to surpass 80px, it seems like I can only set width up to around 80px and anything higher won't do anything.

If I leave the thumbnails like they are without trying the above CSS code they appear too small on mobile devices and **I need a way to increase the size of the thumbnails on mobile devices only**.

Here is a [link](http://talk.hostoi.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.html?) to the site:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `col-xs-6` to `col-xs-12`

So instead of

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
```

You'll have

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
```

This will make it so that each thumbnail will take up the full width of the phone, instead of having two across.

Comment: I actually prefer two across, I just can't get them to fit to the size I want

Comment: Also I have just tried `col-xs-12` and it only makes the border fit the full width of the screen, the actual images remain the same size

Comment: How big are your images? Try images that are larger

Comment: @user3574492 2 across seems a little small to me when I look on a phone, but it's your call

Comment: Yes I agree... I have changed it to `col-xs-12` looks much better thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem, I found that I had the below code elsewhere in my CSS that I didn't take notice of. This below media query was what made my images appear so small on mobile devices, I took it out and now images appear fine. Thanks for the help guys.

```
@media(max-width:767px){

.thumbnail > img {
    height:40px;

    }
}
```