# Bootstrap thumbnails disappear on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, thumbnails

On my website I am using bootstrap thumbnail gallery. I am using it to try and make the website responsive. 
It works well on a desktop screen and a tablet, but it completely disappears on mobile.

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="http://shopcloud9cycles.com/brand/campagnolo">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="themes/glencoecopy/css/images/logos/campaglogo.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="http://shopcloud9cycles.com/brand/enve">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="themes/glencoecopy/css/images/logos/envelogo.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
```

**I have tried changing it to `col-xs-12` 
and adding this :**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .img-responsive {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    }
```

None of this works, does anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: No, images not disappearing at all http://jsfiddle.net/bg61gyy4/1/ any screen size, there must be another css properties which may cause the images not displaying on mobile

Comment: Make a fiddle with the problem.

Comment: you need to **use** `col-xs-12` , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24230945/2218697), hope helps someone.